# AngularJS ui-router: force reload

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have an AngularJS app starting at index.html and using ui-router. Based on a trigger I want to reload the complete page. I tried:

```
$state.go($state.current, $stateParams, {
    reload: true,
    inherit: false,
    notify: true
});
```

But that does not work. It doesn't reload my initial index.html.

I can do:

```
window.location.href = "index.html";
```

But then I'm on my initial page, not the current state.

Should a set `window.location.href` to `index.html` with query string parameters specifying current location? If I do that, how can I navigate to this location?

Answer (score 22):

The current trick is:

> $state.go($state.current.name, $state.params, { reload: true });

Comment: This doesn't work if your $state.go is the same $state(). It gets completely ignored and fails silently. 

$window.location.reload() does the trick though. Tested on 1.4x

Answer (score 19):

Everybody seems to have ignored what Serge van den Oever appears to actually be asking, and that's that he wants entire **page** to reload, and not just the route.

The solution for that is pretty simple if you inject the `$window` service into your controller:

```
$window.location.reload();
```

If you just want the route to reload (which seems to be much more common), and are using `ui-router`, then just inject the `$state` service and do:

```
$state.reload();
```

This should reinitialize controllers now that the bug has been fixed, although I don't think it reinitializes `resolve`s.

Comment: Serge van den Oever stated that he want to reload the base html page ("...It doesn't reload my initial index.html..."). I think this answer should be accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me in a similar scenario.

```
$state.go('root.state').then(function(){
    $state.reload();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you include the $route service in your controller you could try `$route.reload();`

Comment: Hi hydrogen, problem is that I am using the superior ui-router  routing system for AngularJS (http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router), not the built in AngularJS routing system.

Comment: Ah I see, in this case you might need to try: `$state.reload()` in order to get it to reload. `ui.router` has a $state service you can inject to do this.

Comment: Problem is $state.reload() doesn't initialize controllers again. There's open ticket for that https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/582

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$state.transitionTo($state.current, $stateParams, {
    reload: true,
    inherit: false,
    notify: true
});
```