# AngularJS UI Router: Correct Way to Change Url with Page Reloading

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I found a solution when I can chage url with page reloading in AngularJS:

```
$window.location = "new_url";
$window.location.reload();
```

It has a by-effect - `$window.location = "new_url"` changes state/route immidiately and you can discover loaded new controller's template and even discover network connections at controler's initialization, only then  `$window.location.reload()` code is executed that reloads the page.
I trided several ways like described here https://stackoverflow.com/a/26853786/551744

```
$state.go("state name", "state params", { reload: true });
```

but does not work for me, it does not reload the page.
This code does not work too:

```
$state.go("state name", "state params", { notify: false });
$state.reload();
```

I use this way, described here https://stackoverflow.com/a/25649813/551744:

```
$state.go("state name", "state params", { notify: false });
setTimeout(function() {
   $window.location.reload();
}, 500);
```

bahaviour very close to needed (after url is changed state does not load new controller and template): `$state.go("state name", "state params", { notify: false });` changes only url and `$window.location.reload();` realods page with new url. But this way has by-effect: I need use `setTimeout` to wait when url will be changed. I don't know why but it doesn't happen immidiately. I tried set 0ms, 50ms, 100ms, but sometimes url changes not fast enough and page realods with previous url.

How can I overcome:

- "setTimeout code" problem;
- or detect event when url is changed  to    force page reloading (it
  can be a problem because code contains `{ notify: false }`);
- or other solution?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to watch for the state change event:

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#state-change-events

Then you can trigger your code to initialise in the controller.

Comment: `{ notify: false }` make url to change but it doesn't rise events `$stateChangeStart` or `$stateChangeSuccess`, but `{ notify: true}` (as default) - does. But I can't use `{ notify: true}` because it is the same as first sample

Comment: Is there a reason you are using $state.go instead of $location.path?
Maybe I need to see some more code to fully understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: I need change url/route/page with page load. I can use `$window.location = "new_url"; $window.location.reload();` or any other ways but they have a by-effect described in question. So i need have an ability to change url/page with reload but without a by-effect of redundant actions