# I cannot load child router if I am currently in child router and refresh browser

Tags: angularjs

This is my router.

```
var studentEnroll = {
                name: 'student-enroll',
                label: "Enroll Student",
                url: '^/home/students/enroll',
                params: {
                    studentId: { dynamic: true }
                },
                templateUrl: stateRoute + 'studentEnroll/student-enroll-base.tpl.html',
                controller: 'StudentEnrollCtrl',
                controllerAs: 'studentEnrollController',
                data: {
                    authorizedRoles: ['admin']
                },
                breadcrumbParent: breadcrumbParent
            };
            var enrollSelectStudent = {
                name: 'enroll-select-student',
                label: "Select Student",
                parent: studentEnroll,
                views: {
                    '': {
                        component: "enrollStudentSelect"
                    },
                    'student-info': {
                        templateUrl: stateRoute + 'studentEnroll/step-student/student-info.tpl.html',
                        controller: ''
                    }
                }
            };
```

I cannot load child router (child template) if I am currently in child router and refresh browser?
If I am not in child router, it works correctly.

Comment: Does your server support your child router?

Comment: *"cannot load"* sure isn't a very descriptive problem statement that provides much detail about anything. Please take some time to read [ask]

Comment: @SGSVenkatesh Yes

Comment: @charlietfl Cannot load means cannot load child router' template

Comment: that still doesn't explain what does happen, what errors occur, what debugging and error handlers have been used etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why I cannot load my child router's template because if I am in the child router, when I click  element, `ui-sref` will not work.

```
<li><a ui-sref="student-enroll({studentId:null})" ng-click="studentController.studentFunction()">Enroll Student</a></li>
```

So, this is what I did to solve this problem.
I use the ForceReload for ui-router.

I removed `ui-sref` from  element. Then I handle the routing in my controller function.

So, my studentFunction() will be:

```
function studentFunction()
{
   if ($state.current.name !== 'enroll-select-student') {
            $state.go('student-enroll', { studentId: null }, { reload: true });
      }
}
```

Please check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26853786/8229192) for more about ForceReload in ui-router.